# Change font size of author name in list of messages

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, fonts, microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook 2013, how do I change the font size of the author name in the list of messages? For instance, in the screenshot below, I want to shrink "Uber Receipts":

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Outlook 2013/2016: Make Sender and Subject the same Font Size](http://www.basics.net/2016/04/26/outlook-20132016-make-sender-and-subject-the-same-font-size/):

In Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2016, the sender is shown in a bigger font that the subject in the email list. This is a change from Outlook 2010 where both lines were with the same font size.

To get that behaviour back, do the following:

1. Go to the **View** tab
2. Click on **View Settings**
3. Click on **Conditional Formatting...**
4. Click on **Add** and give the new rule a name (e.g. "Sender name")
5. Click on **Font...**
6. Under the "Size" heading, click on **Smaller**
7. Click **OK**
8. You will get a warning that you have not created a condition. Click **Yes**

Tested and working in Outlook 2016.